# Labelling and theme of ggalluvial plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend, geom-text

For the past hours I have tried to understand the whole design/theme/labelling concept around *ggalluvial*, but I failed.
Within minutes I was able to produce the kind of graph I want (thanks to the package ggalluvial), but I can't figure how to produce the correct labelling/theme I'd like to have.

This is where I am currently:
[image: Almost Done!]

This is where I was initially:
[image: white labels]

To get you to understand where I am, here's a reproducible example

[image: Titanic Alluvial]

I used the following code:

```
library(ggalluvial)

ds <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

ggplot(ds,
   aes(weight = Freq, axis1 = Sex, axis2 = Class)) +
geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Sex), width = 1/12) +
geom_stratum(width = 1/4, fill = "black", color = "grey") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Sex", "Class")) + 
scale_fill_manual(name = "", values=c("#A0A0A0", "#494949")) +              
ggtitle("Titanic Survival") +                            
theme_bw() +                                                          
geom_text(stat = "stratum", color="white",label.strata = TRUE,
        angle=c(90,90,0,0,0,0) , size=6, 
        nudge_y=c(1,2,3,4,5,0)) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom",
    title = element_text(size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=20))
```

What I would like to change:

- turn labels on the left vertically

  - *done*
- make labels on the right not overlap (not visible with the Titanic data)

  - *I tried nudging. But it may be more useful to place these legends outside the graph, maybe like on an axis?*
- remove y-axis labels

  - *done*
- Understand with what command I can change each of the text elements size (title, legend, labels, axis labels)

  - *dome*

I am very happy for any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if have a reproducible example.

Comment: @Axeman - thanks. I added the Titanic Example. Unfortunately the labels dont overlap there. But in general it's very similar.

Comment: @jimbou - thanks a lot! 1) I changed the labels to geom_text, but now I have some new issues. Rotation is possible, but I don't know how to select the left column only. 2) skipped for now, until I figure out how to rotate only one side 3) didn't work, but I found another solution 4) It's more about knowing how to change each element. Once I know that, I can try and error myself =)

Comment: Two possible solutions to overlap are (1) resizing and (2) repelling. [**ggrepel**](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel) can do (2), but it might get messy. [**ggfittext**](https://github.com/wilkox/ggfittext) can accomplish (1). Might either of those do what you need, based on the examples at the sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ggplot(ds,
       aes(weight = Freq, axis1 = Sex, axis2 = Class)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Sex), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/16, fill = "black", color = "grey") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:2, labels = c("Sex", "Class")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values=c("#A0A0A0", "#494949")) +              
  ggtitle("Titanic Survival") +                            
  theme_bw() +                                                          
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", color="red",label.strata = TRUE, angle=c(0,0,45,45,45,45),size=5) +              
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        title = element_text(size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

- add a vector with the same length of labels like `angle=c(0,0,45,45,45,45)`
- add `axis.text.y = element_blank()` in `theme()`
- pending
- Sizes via `theme`

  - via `theme()` such as x-axis labels
  - text in plot via `size=5` in `geom_text()`